Can't receive LiqPay callback
I'm trying to use LiqPay Checkout for my django website. Everything works great, I can see my test transactions on the LiqPay's admin panel, but I don't receive POST callback to the specified server_url. I can see all the attempts to send callback in the "API call log" and in the "HTTP Code" column it always says "Not Delivered". (url it tries to send request to is valid, and when I try to send request myself using curl I can see it in django's output).
To make site global I used ngrok.
Maybe this is a problem with some Django or ngrok firewall settings?
UPDATE:
It works when I use localtunnel instead of ngrok
